# Accept an array of strings only if it is composed of digits

Tags: arrays, ruby, regex

I'm trying to write an `if` condition that accepts a string array if all its elements are digits. If it is not made of digits, it should return `"incorrect input"` in `else`. Later, I will turn those digits into integers in order to get a square root. This is what I have wrote:

```
def square(string)
if string =~ /^\d+$/
  m = string.split(",").map(&:to_i).sort
  if m.count == 4 && m.each_cons(2).all? {|a, b| b == a + 1 }
    d = m.inject{|c,v| c*v}
    g = d + 1
    r = Math.sqrt(g).to_i
    puts "#{g}, #{r}"
  else
    puts 'not consecutive'
  end
 else
 puts 'incorrect input'
 end
end

square("3,0,1,0")
```

Comment: `string == /^[\d]$/` becomes `[] == /^[\d]$/`. Does an empty array equal a regular expression (object)? No. So `false` is always returned. Also, `if` needs an `end`.

Comment: Loop through the string, and for any specific string...  `"specific_string".match(/^[0-9]*$/).to_s.size == "specific_string".size`

Comment: Do you intend `string` to be an array, a string, or a regex?

Comment: You need to supply input samples and the expected output for those. Your code sample must be syntactically correct so we can try running it. It appears you might be looking for strings containing commas, but without real data that'd just be a semi-educated guess. See "[ask]".

Comment: Regex for this would be something like: "~[0-9]+~"

Comment: You completely revised your question after a couple of answers had been posted, but did not mention that you had done so. That renders those answers nonsensical. Please do not do that. If you want to make a substantive revision, please leave the original question and add something like `"**Edit:** to clarify...."`, followed by the new material. The other option, which may have been preferably, would be to delete your question and posted another.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The regex `/^\d+$/` only checks for one integer. You need to do the following:

```
/^\d+(,\d+)*$/
```

to include the commas.

In addition, if you want to include real numbers:

```
/^\d+(\.\d+)?(,\d+(\.\d+)?)*$/
```

Comment: It's difficult to say *WHAT* the OP wants because there is no input data or expected output, nor is the code remotely clear about what `string` is. Until those are supplied everything is a guess.

Comment: It validates `4.54.234.234.234` as correct, while it should not. Why do people love to shorten the repetition? `^\d+(\.\d+)?(,\d+(\.\d+)?)*$` (`token (separator token)*`) is the standard way to write these construct.

Comment: You are correct @nhahtdh, I updated my answer to reflect the correct way

Comment: I ended changing the regex  a bit, because I didn't take into consideration negative digits:   /^(-?\d+,?)+$/

Answer (score -2):

So this won't work because you are only leaving one space for one digit. You need to add a `+` after the \d in order to allow for any number of digits. The plus sign means that the Regex checks for one or more characters that qualify as whatever precedes the plus sign. You could accomplish this with:

```
if string =~ /^\d+$/
    do_stuff
end
```

Comment: It's difficult to say *WHAT* the OP wants because there is no input data or expected output, nor is the code remotely clear about what `string` is. Until those are supplied everything is a guess.

Comment: Yeah, I guess you're right. I'll be more careful about giving speculative answers.